# Como abrir una url almacenada en mi BBDD firebase desde un boton java en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, botón, eventos

Querría saber cómo hacer que un botón escrito en java en android studio, abra una URL que está almacenada en un campo de una tabla de mi BBDD de firebase.

Tengo el botón declarado en el layout de la actividad, pero quiero saber cómo es la estructura para que recoja dicha URL del campo url de mi base de datos recetas en base al campo Rid que identifica a una receta de forma única, y lo guarde en un string o en la variable necesaria para que un método setOnClickListener con su intent haga que al pulsar el botón, se abra esa url de mi BBDD de firebase.

Esta es mi estructura de firebase:

[image: Tablas Firebase]

[image: Campos tabla recetas]

[image: Campos tabla usuarios]

Aquí en mi actividad perfil tengo un método que lee los datos del usuario actual que están almacenados en la tabla Usuarios de firebase:

[image: Metodo data read 1]

[image: Metodo data read 2]

Lo que necesito es que en mi actividad Main menu se replique este comportamiento, y me este guardando en un string el valor del campo url de mi tabla Recetas, y ese string lo este seteando al button correspondiente de mi actividad. Lo mismo con el nombre, que el set text de cada boton, en el que pone el nombre de la receta, me lo recoja del campo name de mi tabla Recetas, en un string, y ese string se setee en el set text del boton...

Ahora mismo, tengo simplemente variables de tipo string con la url almacenada, a las que se las paso de esta forma, con los siguientes metodos:

[image: Metodos abrir url.]

Espero haberme explicado bien, aún estoy estudiando.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, revisar [ask] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo si tenes problemas para recuperar el dato de Firebase, para abrir la URL en el navegador o ambas?

Si ya tenés la URL, dentro del setOnClickListener() tendrías que tener algo como esto:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Donde la variable url es la url que querés abrir

Comment: Buenas. Entiendo que ese es el método que debo utilizar, pero tengo problemas para recuperar de firebase la url y almacenarla en una variable string para pasársela al método que me has comentado.

Comment: Podrías actualizar el post con esta información? Incluir alguna imagen de la estructura de Firebase y algo de código?

Comment: Actualizado peter1193. He metido lo que creia mas relevante a ver si lo entiendes mejor asi... perdona!

Comment: Lo que yo hago para acceder a una tabla es lo siguiente:

`final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

`final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Lists");`

En tu caso, en lugar de "Lists" tendrías "Recetas". Luego podrías recorrerla tal como haces con los usuarios, de una manera similar a esto

`reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`

    `public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {`

        `for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {`

            `// Aca va tu lógica`

        `}`
`}}`